# How to remove backslash in a string by R

Tags: r

I need to remove all the backslash in a string like below. 
   `x <- ' [{\"Petal.Width\" : 1.8, \"Species\" : \"virginica\" } ] '`

The resulting string I want is 
  `[{"Petal.Width" : 1.8, "Species" : "virginica" } ]`

I tried some methods which don't work.
 `gsub("\\\\", "\\", x)`

Could any people suggest some methods? Many thanks!

Comment: Try `cat(x)` to show that the backslashes are just R escaping the quotation marks. Depending on what you want to do, you might not need to "remove" them at all.

Comment: Here's your Zen moment of the day; There are NO backslashes in the string you offered.

Comment: It's all dandy until you use R to concatenate some string to create a ton of, say, HTML or SQL statements. Then pasting from the terminal into some other app will drive you nuts, because, at this point in time, the backslashes exist.

Comment: 2nd what @MonicaHeddneck says.  And all we get from the SO community is the repeated assertion that the backslashes don't exist since they're escape characters and you can prove your stupidity by cat() the response.  And yet, they get sent across the wire when I use the character string to a REST API, thus screwing up my SQL syntax.  It's an actual problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backslashes are R's way of escaping quotation marks within a character string (see `?Quotes`). It is unlikely that you'll have to remove them. For example, if you're looking to use your object `x` as a title for a plot, the backslashes will not appear:

```
plot(1, 1, main = x)
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome explanation! I tried to export R data frame to JSON for JavaScript. R ends up popping a lot of backslash. Finally it got fixed. Thanks a lot.